# python3 KTinker grid load time incredibly long

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a fairly basic grid which I've noticed generates fairly quickly but takes minutes to actually display anything. It runs through the loop but the window is plain until everything appears at once a few minutes later

```
i = 0
for i,element in enumerate(headerArray):
    label = tk.Label(text=element).grid(row=0,column=i)

for itter in outputArray:
    line=re.split(r'\s{2,}',itter)

    if not (nextLineColor is None):
        nextLineColor = None

    if(len(line) == 1):
        continue
    elif(len(line) == 6):
        for j,col in enumerate(line):
            ele = None
            if(j==0):
                ele = tk.Button(self,text=col)
                ele.config(command=lambda val=col: self.node_selected(val))
            else:
                ele = tk.Label(text=col)
            ele.grid(row=i,column=j)
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: So firsty, ```label = tk.Label(text=element).grid(row=0,column=i)``` creating and griding a widget in one line returns ```None``` so label is always going to be set to ```None``` I cannot actually run your code as you haven't included any variable involved. Also, ```re``` can be expensive and take a while

Comment: How long does this loop take to run? Are you sure that isn’t taking a few minutes? Or, is there other code after this that does a few minutes of work without returning to the event loop? (If so, show us a [mcve] of that code.)

Comment: So my actual code is working well the bottleneck is when I'm running the .mainloop()

Comment: On another note I realized that it slows down almost exponentially as I add items to the grid. If I remove all but the headers it is much quicker.